# Push notification using C# in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, firebase, push-notification

I am facing a critical problem while sending push notifications using C# in ASP.NET MVC. I put the code in the `Global.asax` file and execute it every 5 minutes.

My code works well on localhost, but it's not working when I upload to the production server.

I get this error:

> **System.Net.WebException**: The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send.
>
> **System.IO.IOException**: Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.
>
> **System.Net.Sockets.SocketException**: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
>
> at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
>   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>   at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
>   at System.Net.FixedSizeReader.ReadPacket(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
>   at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartReceiveBlob(Byte[] buffer, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
>              at System.Net.Security.SslState.CheckCompletionBeforeNextReceive(ProtocolToken message, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
>              at System.Net.Security.SslState.ForceAuthentication(Boolean receiveFirst, Byte[] buffer, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
>              at System.Net.Security.SslState.ProcessAuthentication(LazyAsyncResult lazyResult)
>              at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
>              at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
>              at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
>              at System.Net.TlsStream.ProcessAuthentication(LazyAsyncResult result)
>              at System.Net.TlsStream.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
>              at System.Net.ConnectStrea`enter code here`m.WriteHeaders(Boolean async)

Please help me, because I am not understanding what the actual issue is, and my code runs fine on localhost.

Comment: Add `ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12` to the start of your Global.asax code.

Comment: I  add this code , but i got the same error like "ERROR 2019-02-28 17:09:47,500 45473ms WebApiApplication      Push           - System.Net.WebException: The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send. ---> System.IO.IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host. ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host at stem.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)  --- End of inner exception stack trace ---

Comment: I had this error a few months ago in a service that had been running for months.. The problem was with the Tls12 certificates The exact code I used was : `ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 | SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3;` You have to make sure it's being called wherever you put it before you do any requests.

Comment: @Steve You saved me! We're using web push notifications that have been working on all browsers, but lately sending to Edge would fail at the server with above error indicating that the webpush server (bn3p.notify.windows.com) closed the connection. Adding that to Global.asax.cs fixed it.